# How to pass arguments to a WMI method via WMIC command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, wmi, wmic

I am trying to execute the `SetCustomShell` method from the `WESL_UserSetting` class using the WMIC command.  The class is in the non-default `\\root\StandardCimv2\Embedded` namespace in Windows 10 Enterprise.

I already have the custom shell feature enabled, and I know the class is installed properly, because the command:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\StandardCimv2\Embedded CLASS WESL_UserSetting CALL SetCustomShell /?
```

Produces this output:

```
Call                    [ In/Out ]Params&type                         Status
====                    =====================                         ======
SetCustomShell          [IN ]CustomReturnCodes(array of sint32)       Implemented
                        [IN ]CustomReturnCodesAction(array of sint32)
                        [IN ]DefaultAction(sint32)
                        [IN ]Shell(string)
                        [IN ]Sid(string)
                        [OUT]ReturnValue(uint32)
```

This also corresponds to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/wesl-usersettingsetcustomshell), (except it lists the parameters are in a different order), so I *think* I'm on the right track here.  But I've tried to pass the arguments in a number of different ways, and `wmic` just doesn't seem to understand what I'm trying to do.

I've tried named parameters (i.e. shell=xxx, Sid=xxx, etc.), enclosing the whole list in quotes, enclosing just the values in quotes, calling with parenthesis, and just blasting it with comma-separated values.  Nothing seems to work.  I always wind up with:

```
Invalid named parameter list.
Hint: <named param list> ::= <named param> | <named param> <named param list> where <named param> ::= <param name>=<param value>
```

Or:

```
Invalid format.
Hint: <paramlist> = <param> [, <paramlist>].
```

How do I call this method properly?

Ironically, I know how to do this with a VBScript or PowerShell.  There are numerous examples on how to do this with a script in all sorts of languages.  But I need to execute it from a group policy or during an OS deployment without having to rely on a script file being available somewhere where the client can see it, and this *should* be something I can do with a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like the following:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\StandardCimv2\Embedded CLASS WESL_UserSetting CALL SetCustomShell Sid="s-1-*" Shell="cmd.exe" DefaultAction=0 CustomReturnCodes=(0,1,2) CustomReturnCodesAction=(0,1,2)
```